# MYSQL: evaluating a missing row into a result

Tags: mysql

I am trying to fetch records from 2 tables mapped by an id where on the second table there may be a row that is missing.

I have a column called name on the second table which contains a string value. The value I need to extract is 'subscriptions' but this does not always exist in the table. There is the possibility to have different values within this column which I do not want to extract.

Is it possible to check to see if the value exists and if it doesn't output null to all the fields.

So far I have this which returns all the records

```
select COUNT(*) 
from PUser a, PAttribute b
where exists (select null 
              from PAttribute c 
              where c.name = 'subscriptions' or c.name is null) 
   and a.id = b.userid;
```

Hope that explains it.

EDIT

PUser table

id
other columns

PAttribute table

userid mapped to PUser.id
name

Now a userid can have multiple rows each with a different value in name eg, 'subscriptions', 'source', 'etc' 'etc'

I want to fetch all users who have the value 'subscriptions' in the name column or if the row doesnt exist with the value 'subscriptions' as they may not have any.

If they don't have this row the output should be null.

EDIT 2:

Worked this out and I needed

```
select COUNT(*),(select b.stringValue from PAttribute b where b.userid = a.id and b.name = 'subscriptions') from PUser a order by a.id desc;
```

Comment: I don't understand the (select null ...) subquery; it isn't related to the records used in the rest of the query, and thus is asking if ANY record has 'subscriptions' or NULL for a name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is using implicit joins, which are inner joins. This means that a result will only be returned if a row exists in both tables. Instead, you need to use a left join. Change your query to this:

```
select COUNT(*)  
from PUser a LEFT JOIN PAttribute b ON a.id = b.userID
where exists (select null  
              from PAttribute c  
              where c.name = 'subscriptions' or c.name is null);
```

Or (not exactly sure what your desired behavior is), this might work for you:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM PUser a LEFT JOIN PAttribute b ON a.id = b.userID
WHERE b.name = 'subscriptions' OR b.name IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude rows that do not contain 'subscriptions', you could use the JOIN ON form and in order to keep rows from PUser even there is no matching row  from PAttribute with name set to 'subrciptions', and thus obtaining null fields, exploit OUTER JOIN.

```
select COUNT(*) 
from PUser a OUTER JOIN PAttribute b ON ( a.id = b.userid AND b.name = 'subscriptions' )
;
```

This is a little bit different from your query: EXISTS is less perfomant and, moreover, the SELECT in the EXISTS does search for a row in PAttribute with name equal to null, that is quite different from handling missing rows.